# Trouble with converting dec into hex for C

Tags: c, hex

Using the following libraries only:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I need a efficient way to convert a decimal to a hex in the following:

```
int iteration (arguments...) {
//calculate the number of iterations for this function to do something
return iterations; //returns in decimal, e.g. 70
}

char hello = (iteration in hex);
```

**What would the code for (iteration in hex) look like?**

I have heaps of loops so there would be a lot of converting to hex, the more efficient the better (though I'm pretty sure that there's a function to do this).

Comment: What do you imagine `hello`'s type would be?

Comment: I can't even figure out what it is you're trying to do reading that.

Comment: Hexadecimal isn't a type, it's simply a different way of counting, and/or a way to format a numeric data  for printing.  46 hex = 70 decimal.  Unless I'm missing something ...

Comment: My apologies @Brain... it's been a late night and I'm stressed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing like returning an `int` as a decimal. `int` have an internal representation in C that have not much to do with our way of representing numbers for humans.

In C you can assign numbers that are written in octal, decimal or hexadecimal notation to an `int`. It then contains the "abstract" number so to speak.

```
int a = 073; // starting with 0, interpreted as octal
int b = 23;  // starting with another digit, decimal
int c = 0xA3 // starting with 0x, hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question I believe what you want is
    printf("%x", iteration);
or
    printf("%X", iteration);

Answer (score 0):

The last byte of an integer is assignable to `char`.

```
char hello = iteration(...) & 0xff;
```

As for the rest, a number is a number; "conversion" to hexadecimal only matters for output.